# Laravel mail queue example configuration

Tags: laravel

In a webshop im making I want to send a newsletters to many mail adresses at once. I found an option in laravel to [queue mails](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#queueing-mail) like:

```
Mail::queue('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
    //
});
```

with the text

> This method will automatically take care of pushing a job onto the
>   queue to send the mail message in the background. Of course, you will
>   need to **[configure](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#introduction)** your queues before using this feature.

In the `config/queue.php` I have

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync'),
```

In the docs for the configuration it explains how to create queue jobs. Do i need to make a job for the mail example, or do I only need to make seperate jobs for other custom queue jobs?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but I recommend using something like MailChimp or SendGrid or similar for email blasts instead of doing it via your own application. It will reduce the chances of having to deal with your server being marked for spam, remove some of the load from your server, and give you a ton of additional stats and features like unsubscribe.

Comment: @JoshJanusch thanks, im using gmail for business, so it's not a custom mail server but it's send from gmail.

Answer (score 0):

sync driver is basically intended for development purposes usually, use database driver instead.

In order to use the database queue driver, you will need a database table to hold the jobs. To generate a migration that creates this table, run the queue:table Artisan command. Once the migration is created, you may migrate your database using the migrate command:

```
php artisan queue:table

php artisan migrate
```